# need to migrate single label domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, exchange-2007, admt

Our company has 8 sites, all on different subnets and connected via (slow) MPLS,  and about 250 users in AD, and Exchange 2007.

The current infrastructure was put into place prior to me coming on board here. We have a single domain that was implemented as a “Single Label Domain” - the domain name is "xyz" not "xyz.local"  We have come to understand that this is extremely problematic and is inhibiting future growth.

From what we've seen so far it looks like we can't just rename the domain, and it looks like we will have to create a new domain and use the ADMT tool to migrate to it? Once consultant suggested that we create a separate instance of a Exchange as a "resource domain" and migrate to it - first, and then rename or migrate the main domain.

My biggest concern is the risk - figuring out a way to change the domain without causing disruption to the company - users who can't log in, scripts that break, things that rely on how AD is organized, etc. Ideally I'd like to do this in a staged fashion, if that's possible - rather than scrambling to get it done over a weekend.

Any suggestions on how to go about this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought about adding trust relationships between your new built up domain and the old ones ? - Generally there is no way around of reconfiguring your scripts but you should use this situation and change as much as possible from scripts to group policy preferences.